# Mock a method that's inside a final class using Mockito

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mockito

There is this class

```
public final class PolicySummaryUtils {
   public PolicySummaryResponse.Policy getPolicy() {
       return getPolicySummaryResponse().accounts.get(0).policies.get(0);
   }
}

 public static class Policy {
    @Expose
    public String sCode;
    @SerializedName("policySource")
}
```

I need to mock the state code inside viewModelTest. Is it possible to mock this? I have mocked policy and sCode is returned as `null`

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class ViewModelTest{

    @Mock
    lateinit var summaryUtils: PolicySummaryUtils

    @Mock
    lateinit var policy: Policy

    @Test
    fun payBill_return_acceptedPayBillResponse(){
        return runTest {
            Mockito.when(summaryUtils.policyNumber).thenReturn(MOCK_POLICY_NO)
            Mockito.when(summaryUtils.policy).thenReturn(policy)
            Mockito.when(policy.stateCode).thenReturn(MOCK_STATE_CODE)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write a testable code. Example in your case, Your class is final and cannot be mocked, then your class can implement an interface, then you can absolutely mock the methods of the interface.

> Your class is final and cannot be mocked

Why? Because a final class cannot be extended. By mocking a class/interface, the technique behind is it creates a subclass extends/implements the class/interface. Then if your class prevents extending by having `final`, you cannot mock it.

Note: you can use some power libs to mock final class (e.g. - powermockito), but I would not recommend this.

Comment: Hi what If I change final class to just a public class!! then will it work?

Comment: Ah yes, without final, would be okay

Comment: But... consider to write as TDD and testable code. I believe there's a lot of articles about this for you to search.

Comment: I highly recommend you to have an interface.

Comment: I tried removing the final but was not able to mock policy.So I tried with an interface and it's working.

Comment: It should work for class without final too, but maybe just missing something - I can't read the full code so I can't give further advise here. But glad to see it works for you using interface, it's still better to use interface.